# How to exit clean from WebAPI background service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, threadpool

The code below is a Web API that prints on behalf of a SPA. For brevity I've omitted `using` statements and the actual printing logic. That stuff all works fine. The point of interest is refactoring of the printing logic onto a background thread, with the web api method enqueuing a job. I did this because print jobs sent in quick succession were interfering with each other with only the last job printing.

It solves the problem of serialising print jobs but raises the question of how to detect shutdown and signal the loop to terminate.

```
namespace WebPrint.Controllers
{
    public class LabelController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly ConcurrentQueue<PrintJob> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<PrintJob>();
        static bool running = true;
        static LabelController()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => {
                while (running)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(30);
                    if (queue.TryDequeue(out PrintJob job))
                    {
                        this.Print(job);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        public void Post([FromBody]PrintJob job)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(job);
        }

    }
    public class PrintJob
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string html { get; set; }
        public string printer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Given the way I acquire a thread to servicing the print queue, it is almost certainly marked as a background thread and should terminate when the app pool tries to exit, but I am not certain of this, and so I ask you, dear readers, for your collective notion of best practice in such a scenario.

---

Well, I *did* ask for best practice.

Nevertheless, I don't have long-running background tasks, I have short-running tasks. They arrive asynchronously on different threads, **but must be executed serially and on a single thread** because the WinForms printing methods are designed for STA threading.

Matt Lethargic's point about possible job loss is certainly a consideration, but for this case it doesn't matter. Jobs are never queued for more than a few seconds and loss would merely prompt operator retry.

For that matter, using a message queue doesn't solve the problem of "what if someone shuts it down while it's being used" it merely moves it to another piece of software. A lot of message queues aren't persistent, and you wouldn't believe the number of times I've seen someone use MSMQ to solve this problem and then fail to configure it for persistence.

This has been very interesting.

http://thecodelesscode.com/case/156

Comment: This design should be reviewed. The controller appears to be doing too much. Also trying to use background threads in this way will eventually cause problem.

Comment: create a service independent of the controller to manage the queue and printing. The sole job of the controller in the above scenario is to queue the job

Comment: Use an [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.7.2) and check it often. In Global.asax we have the `Application_End` event.

Comment: Given that the whole shebang is less than eighty LoC and the web method has a one line body I don't think separating the parts would reduce complexity.

Comment: A lot of options are outlined [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx), for example using the QueueBackgroundWorkItem

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Write that as an answer -- you have actually answered the question.

Comment: @PeterBons Thanks, although you haven't answered the question as asked, I was unaware of QBWI and it's exactly appropriate.

Comment: @PeterWone appreciated the story completely. very interesting indeed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the desired behavior is not something that should be done within a Controller.

```
public interface IPrintAgent {
    void Enqueue(PrintJob job);
    void Cancel();
}
```

The above abstraction can be implemented and injected into the controller using the frameworks `IDependencyResolver`

```
public class LabelController : ApiController {
    private IPrintAgent agent;

    public LabelController(IPrintAgent agent) {
        this.agent = agent;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]PrintJob job) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            agent.Enqueue(job);
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

The sole job of the controller in the above scenario is to queue the job.

Now with that aspect out of the way I will focus on the main part of the question.

As already mentioned by others, there are many ways to achieve the desired behavior

A simple in memory implementation can look like

```
public class DefaultPrintAgent : IPrintAgent {
    static readonly ConcurrentQueue<PrintJob> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<PrintJob>();
    static object syncLock = new Object();
    static bool idle = true;
    static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    static DefaultPrintAgent() {
        checkQueue += OnCheckQueue;
    }

    private static event EventHandler checkQueue = delegate { };
    private static async void OnCheckQueue(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        PrintJob job = null;
        while (!queue.IsEmpty && queue.TryDequeue(out job)) {
            await Print(job);
            if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) {
               break;
            }
        }
        idle = true;
    }

    public void Enqueue(PrintJob job) {
        queue.Enqueue(job);
        if (idle) {
            lock (syncLock) {
                if (idle) {
                    idle = false;
                    checkQueue(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Cancel() {
        if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            cts.Cancel();
    }

    static Task Print(PrintJob job) {
        //...print job
    }
}
```

which takes advantage of async event handlers to process the queue in sequence as jobs are added.

The `Cancel` is provided so that the process can be short circuited as needed.

Like in `Application_End` event as suggested by another user

```
var agent = new DefaultPrintAgent();
agent.Cancel();
```

or manually by exposing an endpoint if so desired.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at your architecture at a higher level, doing 'long running tasks' such as printing should probably live outside of you webapi process entirely.

If this we myself I would:

Create a windows service (or what have you) that has all the printing logic in it, the job of the controller is then to just talk to the service either by http or some kind of queue MSMQ, RabbitMQ, ServiceBus etc.

If via http then the service should internally queue up the print jobs and return 200/201 to the controller as soon as possible (before printing happens) so that the controller can return to the client efficiently and release it's resources.

If via a queuing technology then the controller should place a message on the queue and again return 200/201 as quick as possible, the service can then read the messages at it's own rate and print one at a time.

Doing it this way removes overhead from your api and also the possibility of losing print jobs in the case of a failure in the webapi (if the api crashes any background threads may/will be effected). Also what if you do a deployment at the point of someone printing, there's a high chance the print job will fail.

My 2 cents worth

Comment: The OP's reluctance to accept clean design suggestions reminds me of a saying *If you do not take the time to do it right, when will you have the time to do it over?*

Comment: @Nkosi, I'm printing label stickers, not forty page Word documents. They print subsecond but I send them in bursts of two or three. I was only getting the last one until I used a queue to serialise them. The point of the queue is not asynchronicity but serialisation of transactions. The point of the _question_ was how to signal the queue polling loop to exit when someone wants to stop the app pool.

Comment: @PeterWone then using the queue along with async-await should get you the sequential behavior you desire. That will also lend well with the cancellation token as suggested by another poster

Comment: @PeterWone I still hold that the desired behavior is not something that should be done within a Controller. As simple as it is perceived.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use an articulated lorry where a bicycle will do.